# Conditional insert in EF Core not working as expected using transaction. (Beginner)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the 2 following tables / entities.

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Game> Games { get; set; }
}

public class Game
{
    public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }
    public User Owner { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int GameId { get; set; }

    public string GameName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

I am new to Entity Framework Core and C#. My goal is to create a function that creates a row in the `Game` table, but only allowing a `User` to have a maximum number of games associated with them.

I have tried the following function below. Using transaction did not make any difference. Assume there are 10 records in the table `Game` for a given `User`, and `maxGames=11`. I run the function `CreateGame`.

When the Delay starts, I manually insert a row in the table `Game`. After the delay is complete, the function inserts the 12th row. I expect there to be a rollback, such that the number of `Game` rows stays 11.

```
public async Task<Boolean> CreateGame(Guid ownerId, string gameName, int maxGames)
{
    using (var transaction = _dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())

    try
    {
        Game game = new Game(ownerId: ownerId, gameName: gameName);

        // Count games for the given user
        var count = _dbContext.Games
                              .Where(g => g.OwnerId == ownerId)
                              .Select(g => g.OwnerId)
                              .Count();

        // Conditional insert 
        if (count < maxGames)
        {
            await Task.Delay(10000); // Delay to simulate race condition
            await _dbContext.Games.AddAsync(game);
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            await transaction.CommitAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("Saved");

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Did not save");
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception occurred");
        Console.WriteLine(ex);

        await transaction.RollbackAsync();

        return false;
    }
}
```

Why does the code not work as expected? Does a transaction not work in this case because the if condition is not database logic?

Comment: You call `CommitAsync()` in both conditional branches. `CommitAsync` is how you successfully end a transaction and indicate that the changes made during the transactions should be saved. You need to *roll back* the transaction if you don't want to save the changes made during it to be persisted.

Comment: @DanielMann Thanks for the reply. I have added rollback call inside the catch bracket, but no exceptions are thrown.

Comment: Unless I'm misreading your question, you *also* want to roll back in the `else` condition.

Comment: where did you raise exception?
when app arrived line "await Task.Delay(10000);"
app doesn't check the line "if (count < maxGames)" that You expected raise exception after  manually insert a row 
app was  going to next line "await _dbContext.Games.AddAsync(game);"

Comment: *Does not work as expected* is not a helpful problem description. Are we required to guess exactly what is happening?

Comment: This code doesn't make sense. Why are you using a transaction in the first place? What are you trying to achieve? What are your expectancies of "a transaction"?

Comment: @JonathanWood @JHbonarius Sorry for not being more clear. I only want to perform the insert if `(count < maxGames)` is true. If the condition becomes false during the `Task.Delay`, then i do not want to perform the insertion. I use the `Task.Delay` so that I get time to do a insertion manually to make the condition false, for debugging purpose. I thought that using a transaction would lead to an exception being thrown when the count is changed during the delay, such that the condition is no longer true.

Comment: I'm afraid you misunderstand what a transaction does. It can be seen like a container for a number changes that only get applied if the transaction is completed. You have only one change, so don't need the transaction. You assuming that the condition gets reevaluated after the delay is false. You would have to implement complex logic on the database side to achieve that. Or implement some kind of special repository yourself that does it. Calling `Count` just gives one fixed answer. (Note the existence of `CountAsync`).

Comment: I.e. you have to determine `count` _again_ after the delay and reevaluate the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply. But I wasn't able to post a proper answer.

To get to the point, your final question *"Does a transaction not work in this case because the if condition is not database logic?"* summarizes a number of misunderstandings, about the database, entity framework, but also the language C# itself.

[Entity Framework (Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/) is a so-called [object-relational mapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93relational_mapping). That means it maps the data stored in the database to C# objects based on the class definition. Entity Framework Core specifically is a successor to [LINQ-to-entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/linq-to-entities), where you use LINQ to build a query for the database, after which you execute it.
i.e.:

```cs
_dbContext
   .Games
   .Where(g => g.OwnerId == ownerId)
   .Select(g => g.OwnerId)
```

will build the (SQL) query (something like `select * from games where ownerid = 123`), and

```cs
.Count();
```

will send the query to the database and map the result to the specific data type (`int` in this case). (count is actually a special case that slightly modifies the query, because the database can do the counting for you, which is more efficient than fetching all the object to C# and doing it in memory, but that aside)

i.e. `count` is a determined *before* the if-statement.

Next, an if-statement itself is a [branching statement](https://press.rebus.community/programmingfundamentals/chapter/branching-statements/). And since C# is a sequential [imperative programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming). for the if-statement, this means that the condition is evaluated only once, and the branch is chosen after that. It's not like the condition is re-evaluated for every new line. If you want to re-evaluate the statement, you have to do that manually. And that's by design, as constant re-evaluations would be very costly.

Note, it *is* possible to put logic in the database to check certain conditions. However, that's also limiting: it is always applied, so that once exceptional case where you don't want that, life is hard. It's also harder to implement and to maintain.

Finally about transactions. Like I say in the comments, [Transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions) can be seen as a safety-buffer mechanism for data operations. Say you're a bank and you have to send money from one account to the other. So you subtract the amount from one account/database object and add it to the other. But if anything goes wrong, you don't want the money to get "lost" (angry customer, as they lost money) or added double (you lose money). So you put everything in an transaction, which ensures that if anything goes wrong, nothing is changed.

In practice this mean you open/begin the transaction, perform some actions and call `transaction.Commit()` to finalize. If the transaction object is disposed *before* `.Commit()` is called, changes within the transaction scope are automatically rolled back. I.e. No need for manual roll back.

In you case there is only one database action, so there is no need or added value to the transaction. And like said, it's not like the database will throw an exception, and if it did `SaveChangesAsync()` would fail.

So all you need is

```cs
public async Task<bool> CreateGame(Guid ownerId, string gameName, int maxGames)
{
    var game = new Game(ownerId, gameName);

    // Count games for the given user
    var count = await _dbContext
        .Games
        .Where(g => g.OwnerId == ownerId)
        //.Select(g => g.OwnerId) // not needed!
        .CountAsync();

    if (count >= maxGames) return false;

    await Task.Delay(10000); // Delay to simulate race condition <-- what do you mean?

    // AGAIN Count games for the given user
    count = await _dbContext
        .Games
        .CountAsync(g => g.OwnerId == ownerId); // you can actually put the filter expression here!

    if (count >= maxGames) return false;

    try
    {
        await _dbContext.Games.AddAsync(game);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Saved");
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) // try to be specific when catching exceptions.
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception occurred");
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since rollback statement is located inside catch block, you need to throw it from else statement onto catch block, only then the code there will run.

```
public async Task<Boolean> CreateGame(Guid ownerId, string gameName, int maxGames)
{
    using (var transaction = _dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())

    try
    {
        Game game = new Game(ownerId: ownerId, gameName: gameName);

        // Count games for the given user
        var count = _dbContext.Games
                              .Where(g => g.OwnerId == ownerId)
                              .Select(g => g.OwnerId)
                              .Count();

        // Conditional insert 
        if (count < maxGames)
        {
            await Task.Delay(10000); // Delay to simulate race condition
            await _dbContext.Games.AddAsync(game);
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            await transaction.CommitAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("Saved");

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Did not save");
            throw new Exception ();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception occurred");
        Console.WriteLine(ex);

        await transaction.RollbackAsync();

        return false;
    }
}
```

The second approach is to get rid of try catch block altogether

```
public async Task<Boolean> CreateGame(Guid ownerId, string gameName, int maxGames)
{
    using (var transaction = _dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())

    
    Game game = new Game(ownerId: ownerId, gameName: gameName);

     // Count games for the given user
     var count = _dbContext.Games
                              .Where(g => g.OwnerId == ownerId)
                              .Select(g => g.OwnerId)
                              .Count();

     // Conditional insert 
     if (count < maxGames)
     {
         await Task.Delay(10000); // Delay to simulate race condition
         await _dbContext.Games.AddAsync(game);
         await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
         await transaction.CommitAsync();

         Console.WriteLine("Saved");

         return true;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Did not save");

        await transaction.RollbackAsync();

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't seems to fully understand transactions. Just like the other answer and the OP. Your anwer is actually almost the same as the other answer (which was downvoted already)

Answer (score -1):

Because you want checked this condition " if (count < maxGames) "after Run code line "await Task.Delay(10000);" and save manually rows that if (condition ==true) call Rollback.you must modify this code.

I changed  line Delay and add Rollback in line else

My code:

```
await Task.Delay(10000); // Delay to simulate race condition
                // Conditional insert 
                if (count < maxGames)
                {
                    
                    await _dbContext.Games.AddAsync(game);
                    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                    await transaction.CommitAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine("Saved");
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Did not save");
await transaction.RollbackAsync();
                    return false;
                }
```

your Code:

```
// Conditional insert 
        if (count < maxGames)
        {
            await Task.Delay(10000); // Delay to simulate race condition
            await _dbContext.Games.AddAsync(game);
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            await transaction.CommitAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("Saved");

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Did not save");
            return false;
        }
```

I think this code is better according to your situation

```
public async Task<Boolean> CreateGame(Guid ownerId, string gameName, int maxGames)
{
    try
    {
        Game game = new Game(ownerId: ownerId, gameName: gameName);
        // Count games for the given user
        var count = _dbContext.Games
                              .Where(g => g.OwnerId == ownerId)
                              .Select(g => g.OwnerId)
                              .Count();
        await Task.Delay(10000); // Delay to simulate race condition
        // Conditional insert 
        if (count < maxGames)
        { 
            await _dbContext.Games.AddAsync(game);
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Did not save");
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception occurred");
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: According to the code, it doesn't need a transaction, but I guessed that there is only apart of code and the other part of the code(part didn't in this post) is needed.

Comment: You don't need to manually roll back, unless there are specific circumstances. The question doesn't make sense and you just write some answer (which also doesn't make sense). That's why I downvoted.

Comment: Thank you.There is no problem. I gave the required answer based on the requester. Otherwise, the code is not logical

Comment: This code does not need a transaction at all, but I said maybe it is part of the code .It would have been better if he had received the data first and then checked, and if there was an error, the transaction would be Rollback

Comment: thank you for your opinion,I also put my ideal code

Comment: @JHBonarius maybe the logic, flow and syntax of OP question is wrong, but the question is very understandable and logic from business rule perspective. We just try to help him

Comment: @FitriHalim but you either didn't read the question properly or don't understand what he is saying. You are just making the same mistake he is making by trying to fix his faulty code, based on his wrong assumptions. That is not helping.

Comment: @FitriHalim please have a look at my answer to see what I mean.

Comment: @JHBonarius ok I got what you mean. Thanks 